# php mail function cannot deliever mail when sending links(my own website)

Tags: php

i want to send my website link using mail function, when I send some other links like yahoo  link emails were delivered but when i send my website's link email doesn't delivered.

```
<?php
$activationcode=md5($_REQUEST["email"]);     
$to   = $_REQUEST['email'];
$msg = "
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<h1>HEADING</h1>
<p>We are happy to have you as a member<br> Thanks again for registering We value your privacy and use a variety of security measures to protect your
personal information click.</p>
<p>
<a href=www.google.com>GOOGLE</a>//it works
<a href=www.mywebsite.com>ABC</a>//it doesnt work
</p>
</body>
</html>
";

 $senderemail="abc@gmail.com";
   $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
  $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1" . "\r\n";
  $headers .= 'From: ' .$senderemail . "\r\n". 
  'Reply-To: ' . $senderemail. "\r\n" . 
  'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
  mail($to,"SUBJECT",$msg,$headers);

?>
```

Comment: add code, and what have you tried so far..

Comment: could you able to provide some code.

Comment: i have provided the code. Please Help

Comment: can you provide your actual website link for me please.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably getting caught in the recipient's spam filter when you include the link to your web site.  Part of the problem could be that you are not setting the `envelope sender`.  Try using the`-f` flag in the `mail()` function and see if that helps.

If that still doesn't solve the problem, make sure that your server's DNS forwards and reverses correctly.

Finally, to see if your mail server has a glaring problem that would cause other mail servers to think it's a spammer, try sending a message from your mail server to check-auth@verifier.port25.com. This service will do a bunch of checks, and you'll get a report back with ton of information, such whether or not your mail server's DNS is setup correctly, whether your mail server's IP is on any black lists, if you have a problem with your SPF records, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes to your code and tested on my server and the following worked:

```
<?php   
$to   = 'sendtoemailaddress';
$subject = 'Testing';
$senderemail="no-reply@jaibi.com";
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers.= "Content-type:text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1" . "\r\n";
$headers.= 'From: ' .$senderemail;
$msg = "
<h1>HEADING</h1>
<p>We are happy to have you as a member<br> Thanks again for registering We value your privacy and use a variety of security measures to protect your
personal information click.</p>
<p>
<a href='http://www.google.com'>GOOGLE</a>
<a href='http://www.jaibi.com/admin/'>ABC</a>
</p>
</body>
</html>
";
mail($to,$subject,$msg,$headers);
?>
```

Comment: thnx for the reply but it didnt work... mail didnt delivered when i am using my website

Comment: @MuhammadHabib I updated the code in the answer with your domain as well. Try it on a separate test page and add two different email addresses to $to and $senderemail. Let this coed run on page load and check if it worked and please let me know. Not giving up on you :-)